# how to fix model popup on center of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

i am using model popup on the page. i have table with 200 rows on the page. and when i click each row model popup open. but when i scroll down on the table and click on row. model popup open upside on the page. i want it to open always on the center of the page even i scroll down on the table.

my css is

```
 .modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10040;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (Live: http://ud.ht/gLlF):

```
<div class="modal" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-parent">
        <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="modal-contnet">
                <span class="modal-text" role="dialog-message">This is text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.modal {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    font-family: Tahoma;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: none;
}
.modal-parent {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.modal-container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
.modal-contnet {
    width: 450px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.modal-text {
    padding: 20px 25px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
}
.modal-body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Your content here</p>
  </div>
</div
```

try this, hopes this helps you